# Problema na definição de onClick em runtime com Pascal (Delphi/Lazarus)

Tags: delphi, procedure, pascal, lazarus, runtime

Preciso usar a `procedure ClicaItem(Sender: TObject);` em um `OnClick` criado em tempo de execução pela chamada da `procedure CriaItem(nome:String);`.
Porém, em todas as minhas tentativas, não consegui atribuir `item.OnClick` à *procedure* `ClicaItem`. Como devo proceder se sucede erro referente aos tipos incompativeis?

> Error: Incompatible types: got address of
>   procedure(TObject);Register" expected "procedure variable type of
>   procedure(TObject) of object;Register>"

Peço para me esclarecerem a criação da procedure ao tipo aceito pelo OnClick, além de como devo fazer essa atribuição no evento `OnClick`.

**OBS: O item é criado normalmente em runtime (tempo de execução), porém a linha referente ao OnClick está comentada devido ao erro antes de compilar.**

Comment: Você não pode atribuir diretamente uma à outra pois elas possuem parâmetros diferentes. Acho que mais informação do quê você está querendo conseguir fazer é importante.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sua procedure ClicaItem tem que pertencer a uma instancia de uma classe (objecto);

```
unit Unit1;

interface

uses
  Windows, Messages, SysUtils, Classes, Graphics, Controls, Forms, Dialogs,
  StdCtrls;

type
  TForm1 = class(TForm)
    Button1: TButton;
    procedure Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
  private
    { Private declarations }
  public
     procedure ClicaItem(Sender: TObject);
    { Public declarations }
  end;

var
  Form1: TForm1;

implementation

{$R *.DFM}

procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
   Button1.Click := ClicaItem;
end;

procedure TForm1.ClicaItem(Sender: TObject);
begin
   ShowMessage('ClicaItem');
end;

end.
```